# how to upgrade libpq in CentOS 7.8

Tags: python

I am using a python app, but it get error:

```
Call stack:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 884, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 69, in _worker
    work_item.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py", line 125, in run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "/root/pydolphin/dolphin/biz/RssEntry.py", line 18, in rss_sub
    sources = rss.select()
  File "/root/pydolphin/dolphin/common/db/RssSource.py", line 41, in select
    logger.error("query rss source error", e)
Message: 'query rss source error'
Arguments: (OperationalError('(psycopg2.OperationalError) SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above\n',),)
```

and I check the libpq version:

```
➜  pydolphin git:(master) ✗ yum install postgresql-devel
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package postgresql-devel-9.2.24-4.el7_8.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

what should I do to upgrade the libpq? Now I am tried this:

```
wget -c http://mirrors.zju.edu.cn/postgresql/latest/postgresql-13.1.tar.gz
cd ./postgresql-13.1
./configure --prefix=/opt/pg13
make 
make install
```

problem still not solved.

Comment: `yum install postgresql10-devel`

Comment: I am compile postgresql 13.1 and install but problem still not solved.@NizamMohamed

Comment: What I meant was you missed **10** in the package name. It's not `postgresql-devel`, it's `postgresql10-devel`.